# Vaadin 14 session-local objects

Tags: java, vaadin, session-variables

I have a Vaadin 14 application with multiple views (but no UI). I need store an object per user that is accessible in all the user's views. What is best way to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `VaadinSession.getCurrent().setAttribute(key, value);` to store an object in the current `VaadinSession`. You can use either a `String` or a `Class<T>` key. The object will be available through `VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute(key)` and it will be accessible from all browser tabs that are connected to the same session.